# BSC testnet, how can i get api key from bsc testnet

Tags: blockchain, binance

Did somebody verify as BSC testnet after nov 2021?

-Issue Detail:
Mainet I can get api as https://bscscan.com/myapikey
However BSC testnet, doesn't support API.
https://testnet.bscscan.com/myapikey

[ What I did ]
1.Access API page on testnet.
https://testnet.bscscan.com/apidoc
However I can't find

2.I did just tried without testnet API
However, shows error
"Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: testnet is an invalid address."

3.BSC testnet register page is not working as well.

[ What I expected ]
Verify contract by hardhat

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an api key for testnet.

Kindly pay attention to contract difference between the test and production network for the token contract address you input. Also notice the cname difference on testnet url (api-testnet).

WBNB-Testnet-Contract-Address: 0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd
WBNB-Mainnet-Contract-Address: 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c

Production:
[https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c&apikey=[BSCSCAN_API_KEY]](https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c&apikey=%5BBSCSCAN_API_KEY%5D)

Test:
https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd

For more information check out bscscan testnet developer page.

https://testnet.bscscan.com/apidoc